# Antlr problem with very simple grammar and lexer

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, context-free-grammar

The grammar below yields an error for the input "Person Address=%John%" (without quotes). It lexes the tokens correctly, but then returns that it expects an ID:

```
ID ("Person")ID ("Address")
EQ ("=")
STRING ("%John%")
line 1:21 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ID
```

How can it expect an ID after searchclause has been parsed? It should expect EOF. I'm totally new to ANTLR, so I'm sure it's my error, but what am I doing wrong?

Is the reason that NOT_SPECIAL+ matches EOF? I tried putting EOF in the set but this is not supported.

[*Note: I also asked this on antlr-discussion but this list seems unfrequented or very low volume.*]

```
/* ANTLR Grammar for Minidb Query Language */

grammar Mdb;

start
    : searchclause EOF
    ;

searchclause
    : table expr
    ;

expr
    : fieldsearch
    | unop fieldsearch
    | LPAREN expr relop expr RPAREN
    ;

unop
    : NOT
    ;

relop
    : AND
    | OR
    ;

fieldsearch
    : field EQ searchterm
    ;

field
    : ID
    ;

table
    : ID
    ;

searchterm
    : ID
    |STRING
    ;

AND
    : 'and'
    ;

OR
    : 'or'
    ;

NOT
    : 'not'
    ;
EQ
    : '='
    ;

LPAREN
    : '('
    ;

RPAREN
    : ')'
    ;

fragment VALID_ID_START
    : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') | '_'
    ;

fragment VALID_ID_CHAR
    : VALID_ID_START | ('0' .. '9')
    ;

NOT_SPECIAL
    : ~(' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\'' | '"' | ';' | '.' | '=' )
    ;

ID
    : VALID_ID_START VALID_ID_CHAR*
    ;

STRING
    : NOT_SPECIAL+
    | '"' ~('\n'|'"')* ('"'
    | { panic("syntax-error - unterminated string literal") } )
    ;

WS
   : [ \r\n\t] + -> skip
;
```

Comment: If I remove the call to `panic` from the grammar to be able to compile it to Java, it works perfectly fine on the given input for me when I run it with `grun`. I believe the problem might be with the code that you use to run the parser, not with the grammar.

Comment: You were totally right. The problem was pretty simple but I was so fixed on the grammar that I didn't see it. I used a loop to print the tokens and forgot to reset the token stream. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can rewrite your string rule in a way that avoids Go code in the grammar (for example by introducing a separate token for unclosed string literals or by allowing them as regular string literals, but then producing an error for them later in your own code), I would recommend using `grun` to test your grammar. That way you can look at the generated tokens (`-tokens`) and/or parse tree (`-tree` or `-gui`) without writing any code and you can easily see whether the problem is with your grammar or your code.

Comment: Please @sepp2k, add your comments as an answer.